# How to convert this event method from C# to java?

Tags: java, c#, events, object, delegates

I have this class in C# that implements interface IPhoto:

```
class BorderPhoto : Form, IPhoto
    {
        IPhoto pho;
        Color color;    
        public BorderPhoto(IPhoto p, Color c)
        {
            pho = p;
            color = c;
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Drawer);
        }    
        public void Drawer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            pho.Drawer(sender, e);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color, 10), 25, 15, 215, 225);
        }
    }
```

And this is the interface in C#:

```
namespace GivenWihInterface
{
    interface IPhoto
    {
        void Drawer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e);
    }
}
```

I would like to convert this code in java, this is the java version class I have:

```
package GivenWihInterface;
import java.awt.Color;
public class BorderPhoto {
    IPhoto pho;
    Color color;

    public BorderPhoto(IPhoto p, Color c)
    {
        pho = p;
        color = c;
        //this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Drawer); 
        // How to pass the delegate PaintEventHandler hire
    }

    public void Drawer(/*How to pass parameters*/)
    {
        //pho.Drawer(sender, e); 
        // How to implement paint event

        //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(color, 10), 25, 15, 215, 225); 
        // How to implement paint event
    }

}
```

And this is the interface:

```
package GivenWihInterface;
public interface IPhoto {
    public void Drawer(/*How to pass parameters*/);    
}
```

I have a problem with assigning a delegate and declaring the Object and Event parameters not sure what event to pass as a parameter, and how to assign it as a delegate in java. Can someone help me with this problem?

EDIT:

I tried to use the [Tangible Software Solutions Converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_Java_Converter_Details.html) with no luck, I am still experiencing the same problem:

[image]

Comment: Instead of a non-usefull coment, I'd like to redirect you to here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: I am pretty sure your BorderPhoto class will have a method of type addPaintEventHandler(....some Interface...). What is that interface?

Comment: @MasterChief do you want to know of interfaces used in java or c# example? not sure what are you asking me. I have only one interface in C# example and the equivalent  interface in java both are named the same "IPhoto ".

Comment: @MasterChief I have other classes in this but don't want to complicate the question.

Comment: @MasterChief I have one more class that implements "IPhoto"  interface, it is named "Photo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class BorderPhoto{

    IPhoto pho;
    Color color;

    public BorderPhoto(IPhoto p, Color c)
    {
        pho = p;
        color = c;
        this.addPaintEventhandler(new IPhoto(){
            public void Drawer(object sender, ...other parameters...){
                // put your code here
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void addPaintEventHandler(Iphoto pho){
        this.pho = pho;
    }

    public void onDraw(this, ...other parameters...){
        pho.Drawer(this, ...other parameters...);
    }
}
```

Property named **pho** holds a handler object, i.e. it will handle the draw, so pass it an object which wants to/can handle the drawing, which in your code is an object of type IPhoto so pass it an object of IPhoto.

*Here we are passing the object as an anonymous object, i.e. instead of creating the object beforehand and then passing it, we created the object at the point where it was needed, that too without explicitly extending the interface.*

Once the handler object is attached to the property, you can just **invoke** the Drawer() of the object, and the object will start drawing.

Pass it any required parameters as mentioned in the interface. Most probably it will require a sender object, which here is the BorderPhoto object. This object is needed if you want to call some method of the BorderPhoto object when you draw, like the canvas on which to draw, which is held by BorderPhoto.